# Room database always creates my database over and over

Tags: android, android-room

In my application room database is created from **assets** folder:

```kotlin
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideIrregularVerbsDatabase(app: Application): IrregularVerbsDatabase =
        Room.databaseBuilder(app, IrregularVerbsDatabase::class.java, IrregularVerbsConst.DATABASE_NAME)
            .createFromAsset("database/irregular_verbs.db")
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
            .build()
```

That is okay, when in runtime if I change the content of some rows, add data to the table it does the job. But if I exit the app completely and enter again, Room will create my database again with the database file in the assets so all the data inserted in runtime are removed.

Is there any way to prevent it?

Comment: Remove `fallbackToDestructiveMigration()` it's not for production; it just clears the database every time you launch the app

Comment: @Zain Does it clear the database when the database version changes once, then do not clear it? Or does it always clear the database without looking at the database version?

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. `fallbackToDestructiveMigration()` is indeed not for production but it won't destroy the database on launch without a schema change.

Comment: This is right @HenryTwist .. I didn't express it well, I meant every time running the app on android studio; it will have a brand new database.

Comment: *That is okay, when in runtime if I change the content of some rows, add data to the table it does the job.* are you sure? How are you confirming that the changes/additions have been applied? I suspect that perhaps they are not being applied.  Perhaps use App Inspection and look at the database when making changes/additions (make sure to refresh).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 3 potential scenarios where you would experience, what you are experiencing.

The first is if the changes/additions applied were not in fact being applied. You can eliminate this using Android Studio's App Inspection to see if changes/additions are being applied.

- The following is from a mock-up of your code. When the asset database has 2 rows (run and walk) and two rows are added (skip and climb) when the App is run (i.e. this conforms, in this case, that data is being added):-

[image]

Another potential scenario is if by saying you *But if I exit the app completely and enter again* mean that you uninstall the App and then enter again.

- uninstalling the App will delete the database, so it will be copied from the asset again. So you would lose all data changes.

The third scenario that could cause confusion is if you increase the version number `IrregularVerbsConst.DATABASE_NAME` and have no migration coded to cover the migration from the olde version to the new version (you have no Migrations added BUT you do have fallbackToDestructiveMigration). `fallbackToDestructiveMigration` is basically saying, in the absence of a Migration for the change made to the version number, drop all the tables and recreate them. So if you changed the version number you would lose ALL data.